# How can I retrieve a list of submeshes from ModelRenderable and geometry from a Node in Sceneform?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am having a problem when trying to retrieve a list of submeshes from a ModelRenderable object and geometry (vertices and indices) from a Node. Is it possible to do so with the Sceneform?

So far, I've tried checking the documentation for both Node and ModelRenderable classes and couldn't find anything. There is a RenderableDefinition class which allows to build geometry (and retrieve it) using a list of vertices and submeshes. However, I couldn't find a way to convert ModelRenderable (loaded from an .sfb file) to the RenderableDefinition.